# jQuery - Dynamic linking of elements in order..?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hyperlink

I have two different classes ".Content" and ".Link" that i want to.. "match" according to the position/order.

HTML:

```
<div class="Content"> Content1 </div> <!-- First of Contents-->
<div class="Content"> Content2 </div>
<div class="Content"> Content3 </div>

<div class="Link"> Link1 </div> <!-- First of links -->
<div class="Link"> Link2 </div>
<div class="Link"> Link3 </div>
```

**What im trying to achieve is to somehow *always* link these in order.**

If i clicked the first ".Link" it would let me do something to the first ".Content"

and if i clicked ..lets say the 146th ".Link" it would let me do something to the 146th ".Content"

The *something* that is done to the content what ever it is, it doesnt change. It would always do the same function what ever it would be.

I have no starting point for this, just the idea... How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `index` and `eq`.  `index` tells you the position of the element among its siblings, and `eq` gets an element from a position in a selection.

```
$('div.Link').click(function() {
    var linkIndex = $(this).index();
    $('div.Content').eq(linkIndex).css({color: 'red'});
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g9XUP/)

Answer (score 2):

Get the index of the element clicked, use that index to access the Content element.

```
$('.Link').click(function () {
    var content = $('.Content').eq($(this).index($('.Link')))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 $(".Link").click(function(){
    var index = $(".Link").index(this);
    var content= $(".Content").eq(index);
     //Do Something with content.
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea: I'd use attribute "position" when generating that HTML and then based on that know with what position I am working on. I think it is faster than traversing DOM to figure out position of the element.

If you do not generate the HTML content, I suggest adding attribute programatically via on document loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to put all your content into a single  (aka DOM) object, it is quite possible to manipulate / link these in orders in JAVASCRIPT, using the .nextSibling feature.

Hence... in your case, (link1.nextSibling) will give (link2).